# Reading and writing different file type into multiple sources in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am developing a program in C# which should be able to read/write multiple file types (.jpg, .pdf, .xlsx, ect.) from multiple different sources (File system, FTP, Database, ect.). For now i need only to work with image files, but in the future i will need to operate with other types also, so the program should be extensible. I have read a lot about software design pattern principles but i don't know how to design my program properly to be able to read/write file from multiple different sources... If anyone could check my code and see if i am doing in a right direction and give me an advice how to implement functionality to read/save file from multiple different source.
Here se my source code (for now):

```
  public interface ICustomFile
   {
    //interface which will inherit all posible filetypes
    string FileName { get; }
    string FileExtension { get;}
    string FilePath { get; }
    MemoryStream FileContent { get; }

    void ReadFile(object file);
    void SaveFile();
    void SetFileData(string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath);
    void SetFileContent(MemoryStream content);
    } 

public interface IImageFile:ICustomFile
{//image file type interface
    Image ImageContent { get; }
    void ResizeImage(int width, int Height);
}

public class ImageFile :IImageFile
{
    //image file type implentation
    private readonly IFilePersistance _filePersistance;

    public ImageFile(IFilePersistance filePersistance)
    {
        _filePersistance = filePersistance;
    }
    .
    .
    .

}

public interface IFilePersistance
{//file source type base interface

    void SaveFile(ICustomFile file);
    MemoryStream ReadFile(object fileObj);
}

public class FileSystemPersistance : IFilePersistance
{//File system sourcve

    public void SaveFile(ICustomFile file)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file.FilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.FileContent.Position = 0;
            file.FileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    public MemoryStream ReadFile(object file)
    {
        if (!isValidPath(file as string))
            return null;

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream((file as string), FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
        }
        return ms;
    }

    private bool isValidPath(string path)
    {
        Regex driveCheck = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\$");
        if (!driveCheck.IsMatch(path.Substring(0, 3))) return false;
        string strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
        strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars += @":/?*" + "\"";
        Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars) + "]");
        if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(path.Substring(3, path.Length - 3)))
            return false;

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(path));
        if (!dir.Exists)
            dir.Create();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object instead of FileName, FileExtension and FilePath. Also see [File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx). FTP files are quite different from local files. Also files are stored in databases in many ways, it is difficult or impossible to generalize files in databases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like that advice to use FileInfo:). Well i still think it is possible to implement functionality to read/save files into multiple sources...